# Scroll up menu style with hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Need help. 
I have make some menus with vertical scroll on hover event, there are 3 menus (home,download,contact). The Scroll effect on hover event has worked, but on click event some bug occur (some menus can't scroll down/scroll to grey side with animation) when other menus has been clicked. the bug occur when i clicked menus in some sequence:
1. download then contacts
2. contact then download
3. contact then home

this is my code in `jsFiddle`

and when i run the code on firefox with firebug some error appear after i do mouse over and mouse out on clicked menu.

**Error Print screen:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PchXy.png]

Thank for advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind the freezing of the scroll event, when you click on a menu is that, after you click , the menu becomes disabled, hence your `background-pos` never changes and so , the method `css(bg-pos)` becomes `undefined` and you are again trying to do `(undefined).split()`, which is not possible and hence the animation freezes.

What you need to do is on click, you need to enable the menus again. This is done through this code:

```
$.fn.stopBG = function (x, y, speed) {
    if(event.which == 1){
        $("#home").removeClass('disable1').addClass('enable1');
        $("#download").removeClass('disable2').addClass('enable2');
        $("#contact").removeClass('disable3').addClass('enable3');
    }
    var pos = this.css('background-position').split(' ');
```

I have updated your fiddle, see this one : http://jsfiddle.net/VSTAm/3/

I have tried this fix in chrome...it works properly there.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but still don't work for me sorry :)

Comment: when i tried in firefox 23 with fire but, i found some error "ReferenceError: event is not defined 
if(event.which == 1){" .